# Query Azure Active Directory For UPN and Primary SMTP Address then export to CSV

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory

I am trying to get a csv containing two columns, UPN and Primary SMTP Address.  The primary SMTP address is among other addresses in the ProxyAddresses property and is discernible because the SMTP is all caps, and the secondaries are all lowercase.

So far this is what I have, which returns all of the SMTP addresses in ProxyAddresses column and not just the Primary address with the SMTP: prefix

```
 $licusers = gc .\licuser_trim.txt
 FOREACH ($user in $licusers)
 {
 Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName $user | Select userprincipalname, Proxyaddresses | ? {$_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*'} 
 }
```

Comment: **returns all of the SMTP addresses in ProxyAddresses column and not just the Primary address with the SMTP prefix**, not sure I understand you correctly, do you mean some address start with all caps prefix "**SMTP**" are not primary address? Can you show the output?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Proxyaddresses`, it covers the result from `{$_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*'}`, or change "|" to ",".

Try this:

```
 Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName $user | Select userprincipalname, @{e={$_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*'};name='Primaryaddress'},Proxyaddresses
```

or

```
Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName $user| Select Proxyaddresses | select {$_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP\:.*'}
```

It will return the primary email address indicated by uppercase "SMTP:".